# jQuery Mobile: Updating an input from MySQL table based on a selection from a list

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-mobile

I'm writing a jQuery mobile page (with PHP) that populates a select element and it's option tags with "items" from a table in a MySQL database (the table contains id, items, cost). Using the commonly cited mysql_query and while mysql_fetch_assoc method to echo out the options this works fine. Stripping to the bare code:

```
<?php
    $itemQuery = mysql_query("SELECT shortDesc FROM `items` ORDER BY shortDesc");
?>
<label for="item" class="select">Item:</label>
    <select name="item" id="item" data-native-menu="false">
        <option>Select Item:</option>            
        <?php
            while($temp = mysql_fetch_assoc($itemQuery))
            {
                echo "<option value='".$temp['shortDesc']."'>".$temp['shortDesc']."</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select>
```

I'd like however to be able to update the input element below that called "cost" with the actual item's cost from the MySQL table, when the user selects an item from the list, and I'm uncertain how to do that using jQuery/PHP/MySQL. The cost input field:

```
<label for="cost">Cost:</label>
<input type="text" name="cost" id="cost" value="" placeholder="Cost (£)"/>
```

I'm also not sure if we can get the cost value somehow from the results already returned in $itemQuery (by changing the SELECT to shortDesc,cost) saving another database query, or whether we do have to query the database again to perform a select where the user's selection = shortDesc.

I suspect in different forms, this is a common requirement for developers; essentially grabbing some information from a database based on a user's selection / interaction. I have looked on Google and searched here but I am not sure if I'm using the right search terms to find what I suspect will already be answered elsewhere!

Help greatly appreciated as always.

Comment: You can do this using Ajax by sending a request to PHP and return a JSON value. Or you can include an arribute within option tag contains the value and post it once selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

1) Loop through your query results and write your options and some javascript (i use an Associative Array)

```
<?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT shortDesc,costs FROM items ORDER BY shortDesc");
    $options = '';
            $javascript = ''; 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $options .= '<option value="'.$row['shortDesc'].'">'.$row['shortDesc'].'</option>';
        $javascript .= '\''.$row['shortDesc'].'\' : \''.$row['costs'].'\',';
    }
?>
```

2) write your html and javascript:

```
<select id="yourselect">
    <option>select</option>
<?=$options?>
</select>

<label for="cost">Cost:</label>
<input type="text" name="cost" id="cost" value="" placeholder="Cost (£)"/>
```

3) write some javascript to update your input field:

```
<script>
    var costs = {<?=$javascript?>};

    $(function() {
    $('#yourselect').change(function() {

    cost = costs[$('#yourselect').val()];

    $('#cost').val(cost);


    });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks very much for your reply! I think perhaps your reference to $array is supposed to be $row? Using $array I get many undefined variable errors. $row seems to resolve this. I have trouble though with the line "<?=$options?>". I have short PHP tags off, but even with "<?php=$options?>" it doesn't work. "<?php echo $options; ?>" does work. Do you know what I'm missing in my PHP config to support "<?php=$options?>"?. I'm curious what the equals sign does. I haven't made it to the JavaScript section yet because I expect the line "<?php=$javascript?>" to fail also. Thanks so far.

Comment: I got it working by applying the same logic to the JavaScript bit: "<?php echo $javascript; ?>".

Comment: Nice it works. I are right row/array was wrong (i changed my code). And yes `<?=` is short for `<?php echo`, see also http://php.net/ini.core#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: Thank you again. Very happy to have learnt how to pass data between PHP and Javascript as well. Marked as the answer.